# Get instance of an activity, in your task, from an Intent

Tags: android

Suppose I have activity A in his task 1.

[Activity A in task 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlMw0.jpg)

From activity A (flags: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK) we open an instance of an activity B, B1, in your task 2 ...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Instance B1 in task 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3wPR.png)

Then, from activity A (flags: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK) we open another instance of activity B, B2, in your task 3 ...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Instance B2 in task 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoG91.jpg)

If I now place activity A in the foreground and would like to go to the B1 instance, using the Recent Task Manager I can do it easily; same with instance B2. Could I do this same thing but with an intent directly from activity A? Something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, "instanceActivityB1 or instanceActivityB2");
intent.addFlags(...?);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Activity A with instances created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qtw1.jpg)

Comment: If you tie these to documents with `Uri` values, you should be able to craft an `Intent` that takes you to the existing activity for a document. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents

Comment: Thanks for answering. Surely it is the right address, but it does not indicate the most important thing; how to build and use the URI for the document or task that contains it.

Comment: That's up to you. AFAIK, for your own activities with explicit `Intent` values, so long as the `Uri` values are unique for each distinct activity instance, their actual values do not matter.